# Error when calling stream using streamprovider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to use stream provider in my app, but it is returning an error when I invoke 'stream', telling me that 'the named parameter stream is not defined'. is this not the correct way to call it?

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged),
    ],
      child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Profile Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Profile'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely changed from version 2 to 3.

The parameter got renamed:

```dart
StreamProvider.value(
  value: myStream,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the docs say, the property is called `value`, not `stream`

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider/StreamProvider.value.html